# ICryptoTransform _NewDecryptor doesn't exist, but _NewEncryptor exists

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I'm trying to reflect on the TripleDES like here (the same problem): https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8fdfcce7-3a8a-4271-8557-3df715c80df8/weak-key-cryptographic-exception?forum=netfxbcl

```
TripleDES tripleDESalg = TripleDES.Create();
byte[] EmptyKey = new byte[0x18];
byte[] EmptyIV = new byte[8];
TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider sm = tripleDESalg as TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider;
MethodInfo mi =  sm.GetType().GetMethod("_NewEncryptor",BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
object[] Par = { EmptyKey, sm.Mode, IV, sm.FeedbackSize, 0 };
ICryptoTransform trans = mi.Invoke(sm, Par) as ICryptoTransform;
```

I can successfully bypass weak key exception when encrypting, however when I want a decryptor, there's no such thing as `_NewDecryptor`, there is only `_NewEncryptor` (I checked this using `.GetMethods()`). Is there a possible way to achieve the same for decryptor then? Maybe using `TripleDESCng()` would help (since it has different methods).

Comment: Note that when you are using private reflection there’s a chance that your application can break with any patch install or vNext installation. It’s absolutely not guaranteed stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/tripledescryptoserviceprovider.cs,ec871869f79b83cd) there is no `_NewDecryptor` instead the last argument of `_NewEncryptor` determines the operation mode:

```
private ICryptoTransform _NewEncryptor (
    byte[] rgbKey, CipherMode mode, byte[] rgbIV, 
    int feedbackSize, CryptoAPITransformMode encryptMode)
```

Passing `0` for `encryptMode` indicates encryption, `1` indicates decryption so you need to:

```
object[] Par = { EmptyKey, sm.Mode, IV, sm.FeedbackSize, 1 };
```

To create a decryptor.